Spring Boot build time always the same at /actuator/info
I have a "Hello World" Spring Boot app, with which I use for prototyping, study, etc.
I have noticed that the build time, as reported by Actuator (at http://localhost:8080/actuator/info) is always the same, namely:  1980-02-01T00:00:00Z.
What explains this?
If it was 1st Jan 1970, this would be slightly more understandable.
It is the same value as found in target/classes/META-INF/build-info.properties
$ cat target/classes/META-INF/build-info.properties
build.artifact=springboot
build.group=example
build.name=Spring Boot
build.time=1980-02-01T00\:00\:00Z
build.version=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

The Maven plugin which creates this file is configured simply thus:
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


I cannot reproduce the behaviour described in the question.
application.properties
spring.application.name=demo
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Then run
./mvnw clean install

and
./mvnw spring-boot:run

http://localhost:8080/actuator/info returns
{"build":{"artifact":"demo","name":"demo","time":"2024-12-28T22:53:28.573Z","version":"0.0.1-SNAPSHOT","group":"com.example"}}


Thank you for this. I can take your pom.xml, and see if it reproduces or not, and play "spot the difference" with the project which is misbehaving.

I'm not sure how to do that but maybe it can help you generate a dynamic build.time during each build
1 ) Define build time value of Maven
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</maven.build.timestamp>
</properties>

2 ) Add value to the defined plugin
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-info</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <additionalProperties>
            <build.time>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.time>
        </additionalProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

